# How to Fix Referencing Aliases in Subqueries Two Levels Up in Oracle 11.2

Tags: sql, oracle11g, reference, sql-update, subquery

I have a dilemma where the query works in Oracle 12.1 but not in Oracle 11.2. After some digging up, it appears that in Oracle 11.2, you cannot reference an alias in the outer most query if the subquery is too deep.

In query below, (1) and (2) both reference `LT` from their respective subqueries which are two or three levels nested inside the `UPDATE`. This restriction apparently has been removed in 12, but remains and issue in 11.2.

I cannot use `WITH` clause as this is an update. Are there other solutions that might get this query working in 11.2?

```
UPDATE TBL LT
SET LT.DW = 'W'
WHERE (LT.CID, LT.ID) IN (
    SELECT 
        A.CID,
        A.ID 
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            CID,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY 
                (CASE
                        WHEN ((SELECT F.NET_INC 
                               FROM BUDGET F 
                               WHERE F.TRACE_ID = LT.TRACE_ID ) -- (1)
                            < (SELECT LOINC 
                               FROM MAL 
                               WHERE CODE = (SELECT F.SIZEC 
                                             FROM BUDGET F 
                                             WHERE F.TRACE_ID = LT.TRACE_ID))) -- (2)
                        THEN 1
                        ELSE 2
                 END),
                OC_DT , 
                CID) AS "RANK", 
            ID, 
            G_ID
        FROM TBL
        WHERE RN = 120) A 
    WHERE 
        A.RANK = 1
        AND A.RN = 'B'
        AND LT.STS = 'V'
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could try with `MERGE` instead.

I *tried* (kind of), but can't test it as I don't have your tables. Give it a try, fix it if necessary (no wonder if you'll have to).

(BTW, "size" seems to be an invalid column name so I prefixed it with a "c".)

```
MERGE INTO tbl lt
     USING (SELECT a.cid, a.id
              FROM (
                    -- subquery where TRACE_ID isn't too deeply nested ...
                    SELECT DISTINCT
                           y.cid,
                           y.sts,
                           ROW_NUMBER ()
                           OVER (
                              PARTITION BY id
                              ORDER BY
                                 CASE
                                    WHEN ( (SELECT f.net_inc
                                              FROM budget f
                                             WHERE f.trace_id =
                                                      y.trace_id) <
                                             (SELECT loinc
                                                FROM mal
                                               WHERE code =
                                                        (SELECT f.sizec
                                                           FROM budget f
                                                          WHERE f.trace_id =
                                                                   y.trace_id)))
                                    THEN
                                       1
                                    ELSE
                                       2
                                 END,
                                 oc_dt,
                                 cid)
                              AS rnk,
                           y.id,
                           y.g_id
                      FROM tbl y           -- ... because you select from TBL in it
                     WHERE y.rn = 120) a
             WHERE     a.rnk = 1
                   AND a.rn = 'B'
                   AND a.sts = 'V') x
        ON (    lt.cid = x.cid
            AND lt.id = x.id)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE SET lt.dw = 'W';
```

---

Or, using a view based on your "A" subquery:

```
CREATE VIEW v_tbl
AS
   SELECT DISTINCT
          cid,
          ROW_NUMBER ()
          OVER (
             PARTITION BY id
             ORDER BY
                (CASE
                    WHEN ( (SELECT f.net_inc
                              FROM budget f
                             WHERE f.trace_id = y.trace_id)            -- (1)
                                                            <
                             (SELECT loinc
                                FROM mal
                               WHERE code = (SELECT f.csize
                                               FROM budget f
                                              WHERE f.trace_id = y.trace_id))) -- (2)
                    THEN
                       1
                    ELSE
                       2
                 END),
                oc_dt,
                cid)
             AS rnk,
          id,
          g_id
     FROM tbl y
    WHERE rn = 120;

UPDATE tbl lt
   SET lt.dw = 'W'
 WHERE (lt.cid, lt.id) IN (SELECT v.cid, v.id
                             FROM v_tbl
                            WHERE     v.rnk = 1
                                  AND v.rn = 'B'
                                  AND lt.sts = 'V');
```

Comment: I think using a `VIEW` is more straight forward. For a second I thought since it still uses a subquery two levels deep, it would cause an issue, but apparently not. It works in both Oracle 11.2 and 12.1. Thanks.